# Some issues with `go get cloud.google.com/go/cloudtasks/apiv2`; undefined: grpc.RoundRobin

Tags: go, google-tasks-api, google-tasks, go-get

The subject in question: https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks?hl=ru
Programming language: GO

First, download this package:
`go get -u google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/tasks/v2`
No problem.

Next I download this package:
`go get -u cloud.google.com/go/cloudtasks/apiv2`
An error occurs:

```
# google.golang.org/api/option
option/option.go:153:14: undefined: grpc.RoundRobin
option/option.go:154:42: undefined: grpc.WithBalancer
```

I did the same procedures on December 24, 2019, everything worked without problems

Comment: It seems that a mistake has crept into some of the last commits, because after these manipulations, the `go build` starts working. But `go get` still not working (by another problem)  

`cd GOPATH/src/google.golang.org && cd ./api && git checkout v0.15.0 && cd ../grpc
git checkout v1.26.0`
This is not for solution, it is only for information.

Comment: See this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59705647/docker-build-failing-google-golang-org-api-option They have some pointers in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that on posting in the github page they solved the issue very fast
take a look at the [commit made](https://github.com/goadesign/goa/commit/f8401dec86fa49bc2519d1f6a877bb2e32da056c).

Try to update the library, also if you take a look at @Blokje5 comment you can see that other people have [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59705647/docker-build-failing-google-golang-org-api-option) with some workarounds.

> I was able to resolve this issue by vendoring with go modules as mentioned.